# unable to unmount encfs encryped folder in cryptkeeper

Tags: encryption

I have encfs encrypted directory mounted with cryptkeeper. If I try to unmount that directory from Nautilus by pressing "eject" button it will show the following error: "unmount: /home/xxxxx/Encrypted is not in fstab (and you are not root)"

how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not use your file manager (nautilus in your case) to unmount the encrypted folder.

Simply untick the relevant encrypted folder in the tray applet. It should dismount without any problem. To remount, you simply tick the encrypted folder again in the tray applet.

Answer (score 5):

My educated guess is that `encfs` is mounted as a FUSE module. For that Nautilus is a bit confused as on how to unmount it.

Try using `fusermount` on the commandline:

```
fusermount -u /path/to/mountpoint
```

Where `/path/to/mountpoint` should be `/home/xxxxx/Encrypted` in your case.

Make sure you've closed all applications (including Nautilus) using that volume before attempting to unmount it.

Comment: This is also the method described in the ArchLinux Wiki for encfs: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/EncFS#Usage

Answer (score 3):

Try typing this in to a terminal:

`sudo umount /home/xxxxx/Encrypted`.

Comment: that worked but how to unmount in nautilus?